# Kannel Cant establish a connection with smsc

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel

First time Kannel user here. Trying to set up a kannel sms gateway on our office network but can't seem to establish a connection with the smsc.  Please note that smsc hosts can be telnet on the given port from our network. Below is the bearerbox log.

```
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Debug_lvl = -1, log_file = <none>, log_lvl = 0
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: REDIS: Connected to server at 10.4.163.221:6666.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: REDIS: Selected database 0
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: REDIS: server version 2.8.20.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: DLR using storage type: redis
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Kannel bearerbox version `svn-r5111M'.
Build `Nov 11 2014 15:51:10', compiler `4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)'.
System Linux, release 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64, version #1 SMP Wed Apr 13 00:51:26 EDT 2016, machine x86_64.
Hostname kannel64-001.dev1.whispir.net, IP 10.4.163.216.
Libxml version 2.7.6.
Using OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013.
Using hiredis API 0.10.1
Using native malloc.

2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Added logfile `/app/kannel-telcow/log/bearerbox.log' with level `0'.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Started access logfile `/app/kannel-telcow/log/access/access.log'.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: HTTP: Opening server at port 13176.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [1] DEBUG: Thread 1 (gwlib/fdset.c:poller) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: Thread 2 (gwlib/http.c:server_thread) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Including port 13176, fd 11 for polling in server thread
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [3] DEBUG: Thread 3 (gw/bb_http.c:httpadmin_run) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: starting smsbox connection module
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: BOXC: 'smsbox-max-pending' not set, using default (100).
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [4] DEBUG: Thread 4 (gw/bb_boxc.c:sms_to_smsboxes) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [5] DEBUG: Thread 5 (gw/bb_boxc.c:smsboxc_run) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Set SMS resend frequency to 60 seconds.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: SMS resend retry set to unlimited.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: MO concatenated message handling enabled
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Set throughput to 15.000 for smsc id <smsc-au-telcow>
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <smsc-au-telcow> disabled.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG: Thread 6 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Set throughput to 15.000 for smsc id <smsc-au-telcow>
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG: Connecting to <120.240.136.6>
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: DLR rerouting for smsc id <smsc-au-telcow> disabled.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 7 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG: Thread 7 (gw/smsc/smsc_smpp.c:io_thread) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] DEBUG: Started thread 8 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router)
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: ----------------------------------------
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: Kannel bearerbox II version svn-r5111M starting
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [8] DEBUG: Thread 8 (gw/bb_smscconn.c:sms_router) maps to pid 9708.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG: Connecting to <120.240.136.7>
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [0] INFO: MAIN: Start-up done, entering mainloop
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `10.4.163.219'.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `10.4.163.219'.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[smsc-au-telcow]: Sending PDU:
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7f9990001710 dump:
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: bind_transceiver
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 9 = 0x00000009
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 1 = 0x00000001
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   system_id: "someid"
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   password: "somepasswd"
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   system_type: ""
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   interface_version: 52 = 0x00000034
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   addr_ton: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG:   address_range: ""
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG: SMPP[smsc-au-telcow]: Sending PDU:
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7f9994001670 dump:
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   type_name: bind_transceiver
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   command_id: 9 = 0x00000009
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 1 = 0x00000001
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   system_id: someid
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   password: "somepasswd"
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   system_type: ""
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   interface_version: 52 = 0x00000034
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   addr_ton: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG:   address_range: ""
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [6] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `10.4.163.220'.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:02 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `10.4.163.220'.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `10.4.163.219'.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `10.4.163.219'.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `10.4.163.220'.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:03 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient for `10.4.163.220'.
2018-02-06 00:03:04 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Creating HTTPClient for `10.4.163.219'.
2018-02-06 00:03:04 [9708] [2] DEBUG: HTTP: Created HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
2018-02-06 00:03:04 [9708] [3] DEBUG: HTTP: Destroying HTTPClient area 0x7f999c000ad0.
```

Below is the kannel.conf file.

```
    # Group Config
group = smsc
smsc=smpp
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-id=smsc-au-telcow
port=18766
host=120.240.136.6
system-type=
address-range=""
smsc-username=someid
smsc-password=somepasswd
source-addr-ton=1     
source-addr-npi=1
dest-addr-ton=1
dest-addr-npi=1
bind-addr-ton=0
bind-addr-npi=0
msg-id-type=0x01
alt-charset="ASCII"
keepalive=100
idle-timeout=100
max-pending-submits=10
use-ssl=true
throughput=15
interface-version=

group = smsc
smsc=smpp
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-id=smsc-au-telcow
port=18766
host=120.240.136.7
system-type=
address-range=""
smsc-username=someuid
smsc-password=somepasswd
source-addr-ton=1     
source-addr-npi=1
dest-addr-ton=1
dest-addr-npi=1
bind-addr-ton=0
bind-addr-npi=0
msg-id-type=0x01
alt-charset="ASCII"
keepalive=100
idle-timeout=100
max-pending-submits=10
use-ssl=true
throughput=15 
interface-version=

# CORE
group = core
admin-port=13176
smsbox-port=10176
admin-password=k4nn3l
log-file="/app/kannel-telcow/log/bearerbox.log"
log-level=0
access-log-format="%l [SMSC:%i] [SVC:%n] [ACT:%A] [BINF:%B] [FID:%F] [META:%D] [from:%p] [to:%P] [flags:%m:%c:%M:%C:%d] [msg:%L:%b] [udh:%U:%u]"
box-deny-ip="*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip="127.0.0.1"
#unified-prefix = "00358,0"
access-log="/app/kannel-telcow/log/access/access.log"

dlr-storage = redis

# SMSBOX Setup
group = smsbox
bearerbox-host=localhost
sendsms-port=11176
log-file="/app/kannel-telcow/log/error-smsbox.log"
log-level=0
access-log="/app/kannel-telcow/log/smsaccess.log"
reply-couldnotfetch=""
reply-emptymessage=""
mo-recode=true

group = sendsms-user
username = someuser
password = somepwd
default-sender = 6148993003
default-smsc = 
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 10
concatenation = true


group = sms-service
keyword = default
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
get-url = "http://10.4.163.74/gateway_kannel/KannelEntrance?udh=%u&Command=%k&Sender=%p&SMSbody=%r&receiver=%P&fromSMSC=%i"
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 10

group = redis-connection
id = redisdlr
host = 10.4.163.221
port = 6666
database = 0
max-connections = 1

group = dlr-db
id = redisdlr
table = dlr
#ttl = 1
field-smsc = smsc
field-timestamp = ts
field-destination = destination
field-source = source
field-service = service
field-url = url
field-mask = mask
field-status = status
field-boxc-id = boxc
```

Below is the kannel.sh status output: Please note "connecting..." It should be "online" if everything is well.

```
[DEV.]root@kannel64-001t:/app/kannel-telcow/etc $ kannel.sh status telcow

=== telcow (13176) ===
Kannel bearerbox version `1.4.4'.
Status: running, uptime 0d 0h 0m 4s
    smsbox:(none), IP 127.0.0.1 (0 queued), (on-line 0d 0h 0m 3s)  
    smsc-au-telcow[smsc-au-telcow]    SMPP:120.240.136.6:18766/18766:someid: (connecting, rcvd: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), sent: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), failed 0, queued 0 msgs)
    smsc-au-telcow[smsc-au-telcow]    SMPP:120.240.136.7:18766/18766:someid: (connecting, rcvd: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), sent: sms 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00) / dlr 0 (0.00,0.00,0.00), failed 0, queued 0 msgs)
```

Notes: smsc user name/password, ip addresses have been changed in this file due to security reasons. Can someone please advice on this I'm really at a loss here.

Many thanks in advance.

/B

Answer (score -1):

hello its is all your kannel.conf  file? Avoid attribute without value in your conf.

> eg: system=

I don't see the  SMSBOX-ROUTE CONFIGURATION. 
    You need to configure to forward the flow to the SMSBOX.This configuration work for me.
    Please update your kannel.conf file that way and try:

```
#-------------CORE CONFIGURATION  ------------------------
group = core
admin-port=13176
smsbox-port=10176
admin-password=k4nn3l
log-file="/app/kannel-telcow/log/bearerbox.log"
log-level=0
access-log-format="%l [SMSC:%i] [SVC:%n] [ACT:%A] [BINF:%B] [FID:%F] [META:%D] [from:%p] [to:%P] [flags:%m:%c:%M:%C:%d] [msg:%L:%b] [udh:%U:%u]"
admin-allow-ip = "*.*"
box-deny-ip="*.*.*.*"
box-allow-ip="127.0.0.1"
#unified-prefix = "00358,0"
access-log="/app/kannel-telcow/log/access/access.log"


#----------GROUP CONFIGURATION --------------------------
group = smsc
smsc=smpp
transceiver-mode = true
smsc-id=smsc-au-telcow
port=18766
host=120.240.136.6
address-range=""
smsc-username=someid
smsc-password=somepasswd
source-addr-ton=1     
source-addr-npi=1
dest-addr-ton=1
dest-addr-npi=1
bind-addr-ton=1
bind-addr-npi=1
msg-id-type=0x01after this be assure that the executing user have the permission at last to write and read in the log file
alt-charset="ASCII"
keepalive=100
idle-timeout=100
max-pending-submits=10
use-ssl=true
wait-ack=600
throughput=60


#---------SMSBOX CONFIGURATION  -----------------------
group = smsbox
smsbox-id =smsbox
bearerbox-host="127.0.0.1"
sendsms-port=11176
log-file="/app/kannel-telcow/log/error-smsbox.log"
log-level=0
access-log="/app/kannel-telcow/log/smsaccess.log"



#-------------- SMSBOX-ROUTE CONFIGURATION ----------------
group = smsbox-route
smsbox-id =smsbox
smsc-id =smsc-au-telcow


#-------SMS-SERVICE CONFIGURATION --------------------------
group = sms-service
keyword = default
catch-all = true
accept-x-kannel-headers = true
get-url = "http://10.4.163.74/gateway_kannel/KannelEntrance?udh=%u&Command=%k&Sender=%p&SMSbody=%r&receiver=%P&fromSMSC=%i"
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 10
assume-plain-text = true


#-------SENDSMS-USER CONFIGURATION  ----------------------
group = sendsms-user
username = someuser
password = somepwd
default-sender = 6148993003
forced-smsc = smpp
omit-empty = true
max-messages = 10
concatenation = true

#---end.
```

after this be assure that the executing user have the permission  of writting and reading in the log file

Comment: Please edit your answer, unindent the first lines (that are not code) to show them in normal font, as well as the last line. Please also use proper capitalization and grammar.